# Play M3U8 or TS live stream using Video JS

Tags: video, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js

I am trying to use VideoJS to play a live stream:

https://live.alarabiya.net/alarabiapublish/alarabiya.smil/playlist.m3u8

**(1)** I tried to use a `.m3u8` playlist:

```
<video id='hls-example' class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="500" height="400" controls>
  <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="https://live.alarabiya.net/alarabiapublish/alarabiya.smil/playlist.m3u8">
</video>
```

**(2)** I tried to use a `.ts` video file url:

```
<video id='hls-example' class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="500" height="400"http://www.q7t1.com:8000/live/sYKADDaJs2/SnoQc6v4hZ/186.ts">
</video>
```

Comment: TS is not supported, but Video.js can play your m3u8 file: if you test it here https://videojs-http-streaming.netlify.app

Answer (score 1):

You can try a setup like this (modified from the [documentation example](https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<video id="live_video" width="500" height="400" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
  <source
     src="https://live.alarabiya.net/alarabiapublish/alarabiya.smil/playlist.m3u8"
     type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>

</body>

<!-- Put these JS files together with this HTML file -->
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script src="videojs.hls.min.js"></script>

<script>
var player = videojs('live_video');
player.play();
</script>

</html>
```

**PS:** If Blogger doesn't allow you to upload JS files to same location as your HTML page (*eg:* your blog article), then try loading JS files from some external server:

Replace:

```
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script src="videojs.hls.min.js"></script>
```

With:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
```